# How to create re-usable js library using haxe?

Tags: javascript, haxe

I would like to know as I am targeting javascript, how can I create a re-usable library of my own code, that I can use in multi js haxe projects?

I think to create a library js haxe project, that I will put my re-usable classes, but then, if I compile it, I will get js code, how to use it in other haxe projects?

What I want to do, is to isolate the core logic into a library, and then use multiple views in the html page that uses the same one core-logic js library.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, in case some one is interested, [here it is](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/haxelang/JS%2420modular%2420applications%2420/haxelang/wPiO4UB4YqI/EEuW4_B4ObYJ)